# How to create a chart like this in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I have a requirement to create a dynamic chart like this in the browser

[image]

Users should be able the drag and drop items onto the canvas and connect items together. I'd like to subscribe to events like dropped, connected items, etc. I am not sure what this type of chart is therefore I cannot research to see if there are any ready made JS libraries that do this. Do you know what kind of chart this is? What are some ready made libraries that make working with these charts easier?

Comment: It's a flow chart, all be it, a simple one.

Comment: Look at [GOjs](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably configure an org chart from google charts to match your needs

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart